# How to choose the calendar on Quick Add?

Tags: google-calendar

I'd like to choose the calendar on "Quick Add" instead of modifying the event details once after adding. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not currently supported but you can vote for it here - http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Whitingx in the comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15063/google-calendar-how-to-choose-the-calendar-on-quick-add/109775#comment11226_15063), it is not possible currently but you can vote for it [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs).

The "Quick Add" feature in the mobile version of the Google Calender adds the event to your default calendar.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to quick-add your event:

1. Open the Event "pane", clicking on your calendar, or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
2. Open the quick-add box, by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>

There is no support for choosing default calendar for both #1 and #2. But with #1, if you uncheck visibility of other calendars, then you event will go to the first visible calendar, which is sort of workaround to pick default calendar.